# Removing structural wrap from footer WP Genesis

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, genesis

I am working on a WP Child theme using Genesis and Bootstrap (https://github.com/salcode/bootstrap-genesis). I am having trouble styling the footer without the constraint of the built in structural wrap. What I am trying to do right now is to remove the footer all-together and then call it after the site-container.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'genesis_do_footer' );
```

This adds a footer outside the container which is great but is not removing the original footer, so now I have two footers. I am editing the footer using the Simple Edits plugin.

Any suggestions on how to either remove that footer completely or how to remove the structural wrap?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested with the Bootstrap child theme that you mentioned but this should work:

```
add_theme_support( 'genesis-structural-wraps', array('header', 'menu-primary', 'menu-secondary', 'footer-widgets' ) );
```

And of course move all **genesis_footer_markup_open**, **genesis_footer_markup_close** and **genesis_do_footer** to the *genesis_after* hook as described in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

What you have only moves the footer text (it's confusing, I know!) so you also want to move the markup as well, like this:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_close', 15 );
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'genesis_footer_markup_open', 11 );
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'genesis_do_footer', 12 );
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'genesis_footer_markup_close', 13 );
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but unfortunately the original footer is still there, and now the new footer is also within a container. I will keep trying!